# Django app: best place for a routine on enable app

Tags: python, django, django-apps

I have a project in django 1.10 that has some apps. This project will be used by several organizations, and depends on each of them which apps will be enabled. Where is the best place in an app to include a function that has to be run only when the app is enabled? It needs to create some (main app) objects in the db, as a proper configuration for the app.
Reading [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/#methods) seems that AppConfig.ready() is the best place. Is it?

Comment: Any reason why you can't just use [INSTALLED_APPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS)?

Comment: Yes, I use `INSTALLED_APPS` but when an admin includes there the app, I need to run some starting configurations.

Comment: You can create a data migration to add content to the database. I'm not sure what you mean by "proper configuration". This is usually added to settings.py as well. Do you want to automate that somehow?

Comment: Yes! A migration file can be the way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look at django-admin group permissions. You can use django-admin permissions ideas